# Automator "Watch Me Do" error "-50"

Tags: automator

I created a Calendar Workflow using Automator and I used "Watch Me Do" for one part of it.  It worked fine for me when I tested but every time it would run overnight, it produced an error dialog box saying "OSStatus error -50".  I know it isn't due to security issues because I had already worked through that problem during the interactive testing.

Based on the behavior that it works fine for me during testing but not overnight, I guessed that it might be related to the screensaver having kicked in.  So I tried [using a keystroke to end the screensaver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46019695/7634896) but that didn't resolve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find this answered anywhere so I wanted to post the problem I had and the solution I found here.  The solution was to [use "caffeinate"](https://www.macscripter.net/t/keep-the-screen-awake-while-script-app-running/74564) in my workflow.  The first block of my Automator workflow is now "Run Shell Script" (`/bin/zsh` and `to stdin`) with the script:

```
caffeinate -u -t 180 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

That will end the screensaver by giving the computer something to do for 3 minutes and the spawn at the end ("&") means that the script doesn't need to wait for that to finish to run.  Realistically, you could probably just do caffeinate for a single second and not bother spawning but no harm in doing it for 3 minutes.

After that block, the next block in the workflow is a "Pause" for 2 seconds just to give the computer time to truly be ready to run the workflow.

That resolved my OSStatus -50 problem.

And the way I was able to test this was to use Hot Corners with one of the corners set to "Put Display To Sleep".  Then I would set the calendar event for two minutes in the future, move the mouse to the hot corner, the display would go to sleep and then I would wait some amount less than 2 minutes for it to wake and run my Automator workflow.

To be able to control your computer, remember to add your "app" that Automator creates to have access.  That's in **Settings > Security & Privacy > Accessibility**, click to unlock, then **+** to add your app (if it isn't added already), and click the checkbox in front of it.  I also found that after each edit to the workflow, I had to remove the "app" from the list of allowed applications and then add it back again.  That's a major pain since there was tons of iteration to get this working.

Comment: Nice bit of research. :)